# Create multiple tables named and structured off of a single table with all data in it

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table like so:

```
element code    name    seq active
assessmentCategory  1   Entry   NULL    True
assessmentCategory  2   On-Going    NULL    True
assessmentCategory  3   Exit    NULL    True
careerCluster   01  Agriculture NULL    True
careerCluster   02  Architecture and Construction   NULL    True
careerCluster   03  Arts and Communications NULL    True
careerCluster   04  Business and Management NULL    True
careerCluster   05  Education and Training  NULL    True
careerCluster   06  Finance NULL    True
careerCluster   07  Govermant and Public Administration NULL    True
careerCluster   08  Health Science  NULL    True
careerCluster   09  Hospitality and Tourism NULL    True
careerCluster   10  Human Service   NULL    True
careerCluster   11  Information Technology  NULL    True
careerCluster   12  Law and Public Safety   NULL    True
careerCluster   13  Manufacturing   NULL    True
careerCluster   14  Marketing, Sales and service    NULL    True
careerCluster   15  Science and Technology  NULL    True
careerCluster   16  Transportation and Logistics    NULL    True
cte FT  Full Time CTE Student   1   True
cte PT  Part Time CTE Student   2   True
disability1 05  Gifted without Disability (no longer reported)  NULL    False
disability1 2105    Gifted without Disability   0   False
disability1 2106    Gifted with Disability  0   False
disability1 2121    Autistic/Autism NULL    True
disability1 2122    Deaf-blindness  NULL    True
disability1 2123    Hearing impairment including deafness   NULL    True
disability1 2124    Intellectual Disability NULL    True
disability1 2125    Multiple disabilities   NULL    True
disability1 2126    Orthopedic impairment   NULL    True
disability1 2127    Emotional disturbance   NULL    True
disability1 2128    Specific learning disability    NULL    True
disability1 2129    Speech or language impairment   NULL    True
disability1 2130    Traumatic brain injury  NULL    True
disability1 2131    Visual impairment including blindness   NULL    True
disability1 2132    Other health impairment NULL    True
disability1 2134    Developmental delay NULL    True
disability1 2135    Infants and Toddlers with Disabilities  NULL    True
disability2 05  Gifted without Disability (no longer reported)  NULL    False
disability2 2105    Gifted without Disability   0   False
```

how can I use SSIS or TSQL to create new tables named after the unique values in the element column and containing the values from the code,name,seq,and active columns?

Comment: Can I assume that you know the datatypes of the columns and can hardcode those instead of look this up?  This is probably easiest in tSQL with a cursor and dynamic sql.  I am sure it can be done in SSIS too but even if you want to execute within SSIS I would use SQL Task, what about if the table already exists? Do not create or drop and create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @element VARCHAR(25)

DECLARE ElementCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Element 
    FROM
        dbo.[Validation]

OPEN ElementCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM ElementCursor
INTO @element

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       BEGIN TRY
          DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
          SET @SQL = '
                IF OBJECT_ID(' + CHAR(39) + concat('v_',@ElementID) + CHAR(39) + ') IS NOT NULL 
                    BEGIN
                        DROP TABLE ' + concat('v_',@ElementID) + ' 
                    END

                CREATE TABLE '+ concat('v_',@ElementID) + ' (
                    Code VARCHAR(10) NULL
                    ,name VARCHAR(50) NULL
                    ,seq INT NULL
                    ,active BIT NULL
                )

             INSERT INTO ' + concat('v_',@ElementID) + ' (Code,name,seq,active)
             SELECT
                Code
                ,name
                ,seq
                ,active
             FROM
                dbo.[Validation]
             WHERE
                element = ' + CHAR(39) + @element + CHAR(39)

         PRINT @SQL
         EXECUTE (@SQL)

       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
          EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;
       END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM ElementCursor
        INTO @element
    END

CLOSE ElementCursor
DEALLOCATE ElementCursor
```

Comment: This works for the most part except it does not load the values into the newly created table

Comment: write your select into statement and add it to the SET SQL = statement after the create table.  When you put it in just add the @element variable as the into.....

Comment: the insert statement may need some work but I added it so you could see what I was meaning.

Comment: when I added the insert statement I recieved this:Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 41
The name '
   IF OBJECT_ID('v_pasa') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
     DROP TABLE v_pasa
    END
  
   CREATE TABLE v_pasa (
    code VARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,name VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,seq INT NULL
    ,active BIT NULL
   )
  
   INSERT INTO v_pasa (code,name,seq,active)
   SELECT
    code
    ,name
    ,seq
    ,active
   FROM
    [Validation}
   WHERE
    element = 'pasa'' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: see my 'answer below'

Comment: Provide some sample data with regards to v_pasa because what you are representing shouldn't be possible. I have literally no idea how 'V_pass' could become 'pasa''

Comment: I'm sorry it's getting a little confusing to interact via overflow,

Comment: Can you check the answer below for how the code stands now?

Comment: you are close but you need the cursor looping elements.  So uncomment while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0, and Fetch next From into lines and wrap your begin try in a begin and end.  I will update my answer to reflect your desired naming convention change

Comment: see my answer I edited to have your desired flow, names, etc.

Comment: thank you so much matt for holding my hand through this.  also came up with a nested cursor version but this works much better and is easier on the eyes.  I posted my final rev below with try/catch and all that jazz

Comment: why do you use char(39) instead of double singles or any other way?

Comment: just a trick to not have to figure out the escape sequence which can get confusing especially when the single quotes are at the beginning or end of the string like in this case. Becase '' isn't the escape when that is the case.  to get a string with only 1 quote you actually have to do 4 singles SELECT ''''....who wants to figure that out CHAR(39) easier :)  Your welcome for the help glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the recursive bits for now:

edit: Here's the working code! THANKS A MILLION MATT

my code

```
          USE [vPhiladelphia-CV1]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE jmkParsingValidationTables AS


DECLARE @ElementID varchar(30)
DECLARE @value varchar(30)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 

    SELECT DISTINCT [element]
    FROM [dbo].[Validation]

OPEN MY_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR 
    INTO @ElementID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SQL = '
            IF OBJECT_ID(' + CHAR(39) + concat('v_',@ElementID) + CHAR(39) + ') IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    DROP TABLE [' + concat('v_',@ElementID) + ']
                END

            CREATE TABLE [' + concat('v_',@ElementID) + '] (
                code VARCHAR(300) NULL
                ,name VARCHAR(300) NULL
                ,seq VARCHAR(300) NULL
                ,active VARCHAR(300) NULL
            )

            INSERT INTO [' + concat('v_',@ElementID) + '] (code,name,seq,active)
            SELECT
                code
                ,name
                ,seq
                ,active
            FROM
                [Validation]
            WHERE
                element = ' + CHAR(39) + @ElementID + CHAR(39) 

            PRINT @SQL  
            EXECUTE (@SQL)

            FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @ElementID

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;  
    END CATCH

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```